# How to build 2 dimensional array from a string of options for a select tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, I have a string of options for a select tag. This is my string:

```
var myOptionsString = '<option id=""></option><option id="1">Self Service</option><option id="2">Administrator</option>';
```

In Javascript, I want to convert it to a 2-dimensional Array where 1st dimension will store the id and 2nd dimension will store the text of an option.

How can I do that? I am looking for Javascript solution; I am open to 3rd party solutions also like jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to do this by manipulating the string or by DOM methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by converting the string into DOM options, then iterating over them, so:

```
var s = '<option id=""></option><option id="1">Self Service</option><option id="2">Administrator</option>'

function optionsAsArray(s) {
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  var result = [[],[]];
  sel.innerHTML = s;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(sel.options, function(opt) {
    result[0].push(opt.id);
    result[1].push(opt.text);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(optionsAsArray(s))); // [["","1","2"],["","Self Service","Administrator"]]
```

You can also do it by parsing the string, but that may be more work.

#### Edit

You can also use the new [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), but fairly recent browsers are required for support:

```
function optionsAsArray(s) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var opts = parser.parseFromString(s, "text/html").querySelectorAll('option');
  var result = [[],[]];

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(opts, function(opt) {
    result[0].push(opt.id);
    result[1].push(opt.text);
  });
  return result;
}
```

The above creates an array of:

```
[[id0, id1, id2, ...], [text0, text1, text2, ...]]
```

if you want pairs like:

```
[[id0, text0], [id1, text1], ...]
```

Then the above can be:

```
function optionsAsArray(s) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var opts = parser.parseFromString(s, "text/html").querySelectorAll('option');

  return Array.prototype.map.call(opts, function(opt) {
    return [opt.id, opt.text];
  });
}

// [["",""],["1","Self Service"],["2","Administrator"]]
```

which can be reduced to:

```
function optionsAsArray(s) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, "text/html").querySelectorAll('option'), function(opt) {
    return [opt.id, opt.text];
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RobG. I was actually looking to build the array with string manipulation. I did not know that the array can be build using DOM methods. Are DOM methods faster than string manipulation in this case? Also regarding the element you create in `var sel = document.createElement('select');` line in `optionsAsArray(s)` function, will that element be automatically disposed of after execution of `optionsAsArray(s)` function?

Comment: DOM methods are probably slower, but until you have a string option to compare it to, that's a moot point. The only object that persists after the function completes is the returned array, everything else is up for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery for the solutions below.

If you want the array to be made from DOM then you can do this

```
<select id="selectopt"><option id="">Select</option><option id="1">Self Service</option><option id="2">Administrator</option><option id="3">Guest</option><option id="4">Limited</option></select>

var arr = [];

console.log('====array 1===');

$('select option').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).text();
    arr.push([id, value]);
    console.log(arr);
});
```

If you need it to be made using the string then use [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) for converting the string to DOM nodes.

```
var arr2 = [];
var myOptionsString = '<option id=""></option><option id="1">Self Service</option><option id="2">Administrator</option><option id="3">Guest</option><option id="4">Limited</option>';

var options = $.parseHTML(myOptionsString);

console.log('====array 2===');

for (var i=0; i< options.length; i++){
    var id1 = options[i].id;
    var value1 = options[i].value;
    arr2.push([id1, value1]);
    console.log(arr2);
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmq2r1rk/)

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP wants separate arrays of IDs and text, not ID/text pairs, so `[[id0, id1, id2, ...], [text0, text1, text2, ...]]` not `[[id0, text0], [id1, text1], ...]` but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: @RobG Hmm you may be right. I didn't think of that when I read it the first time. It isn't clear from the question.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you're a landscape or portrait type of person… ;-)

Comment: @anpsmn I am looking for ID/text pairs array

Comment: @RobG I am looking for ID/text pairs array